# Add multiple class Name in facebook developer console?

Tags: facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

I have 2 activity in my android project, adn both activity use separate facebook login, then how to add class name in facebook developer console?

Comment: add two hash Key in Facebook console and provide two Full package Name with Activity name.

Comment: It is possible to add two class name ? @Vasant 1

Comment: yes,it is possible

Comment: how to add 2 class name and both class has key are different or same ? @Vasant